# when will Text widget update after insert a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I create a simple GUI which contain a **button** and a **text widget (TextArea)**. My business is when I click the button, the text widget will be insert some text.

At my attached image, After the GUI appeared, I clicked the button and I'm in breakpoint at line 9, my expectation is the text widget have 2 lines: text1, text2

However, nothing is showed until the function callback is finished

[image: The debug status]

```py
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback(text: Text):
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    text.insert(END, 'text1\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text2\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text3\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text4\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text5\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text6\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text7\r\n')

textwidget = Text(master)
textwidget .pack()
b = Button(master, text="OK", command=lambda :callback(textwidget))
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

My question is How can I force the gui update immediately after execute insert method of textwidget.

**Update**

Thank you for @Saad recommendation, I update the code (insert text.update() at line 9) and I can see the text appear in text widget

```py
def callback(text: Text):
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    text.insert(END, 'text1\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text2\r\n')
    text.update()
    text.insert(END, 'text3\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text4\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text5\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text6\r\n')
    text.insert(END, 'text7\r\n')
```

Comment: _I insert some text in TEXT widget but the text did not display immediately until the mainloop() execute_. The window won't even appear properly before the `mainloop` then how can you able to see the text, I'm bit confused based on your post. If you are not using `update()` or `update_idletasks()` in your main code.

Comment: Sorry for my confuse question. I mean that after the UI appear and I clicked the button.
As your recommendation, I have to call update() method to display the text which I expect.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if this is the exact code. Or you want to have text display without the press of a button?

Comment: At the code in my question, when I click button, I can see that the text is displayed in the textwidget, but when I debug at line <b>text.insert(END, 'text3\r\n')</b> as I mentioned, the textWidget is empty.
So I update add text.update() after text.insert(END, 'text2\r\n').
And I can see the texts when I create breakpoint at line text.insert(END, 'text3\r\n'). Anyway, Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide the non updated code. You can add information to your post by editing the post

Comment: I updated the question. Hope that it clearly enough for my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now I understand what exactly the problem is. As I can see in the picture that you've set a breakpoint at line 9 in your code . what that does is to pause the compile at the breakpoint so we can test different stuff like - *errors*, but this feature is not healthy for GUI at-least on what I've seen. So just remove that red breakpoint in your idle that should fix the issue.

Then you don't have to use `text.update()`.

[image]

Comment: I just want to understand how the text widget update the GUI after execute the insert command. For example, when I clicked 2nd time, At breakpoint at line 9, the text widget still have 7 lines text because the text widget GUI did not update after execute command text.delete('1.0', END). Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I see, do one thing if you wanna see how things update in `text` widget just to see then try `after()` with some delay and you'll notice and can see how one by one line is getting added, it also depends on the delay time you put I think 400- 600 ms ( 0.4 - 0.6 sec ) should be good to notice a difference. In case you don't know how to use `after()` here is [how to use `after()` function in tkinter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method). Also if this helps you consider accepting the answer.